# Lottery Drawings from a public true random seed

Tags: random, cryptography, random-seed

I am searching for the proper PRNG or similar algorithm for my use-case which is a smart contract lottery. Let's say I want to draw a random winner from a list of ticket IDs, my intuition suggests that there may be a PRNG like Xorshift or MT that can be suitably random with a true random seed such that I can generate a set number of derived seeds from a publicly known seed while avoiding the issue of users guessing the next or Nth seed generated in order to anticipate the winning ticket. What algorithm is best fit for this purpose?

Comment: If the seed is publicly known then what would stop anyone from generating the Nth seed in advance?

Comment: this is exactly my problem @PresidentJamesK.Polk. I am thinking maybe concatenating an incrementer to the true random seed and hashing the result may be better than PRNGs for this. EDIT: this would still be precomputable

Comment: There is an area of cryptography called [Verifiable random functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verifiable_random_function) which might be what you need. Note that questions such as this should really be asked on [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) where the experts lurk. Check there and make sure it hasn't already been asked.

Comment: A) Stop the game at a given time, and then check for SNP500's values and generate the seed or the random number from it with a method you predefine. B) Check for a webcam online service (or set up one yourself) that provides the raw photos too, which verifies if the photo is from the HW or manipulated. Then you define what hashing algorithm you will use on that webcam's photo taken in the future.